# How to properly import localForage in Aurelia-Cli typescript project

Tags: typescript, localforage, aurelia

I've been trying to import localForage into my Aurelia TypeScript project that I created using the Aurelia-CLI. I have tried messing around with it in quite a few ways per the documentation on adding references. The library loads if I just reference it in dependencies in aurelia.json:

```
...
"localforage",
...
```

and import it as such:

```
import * as localForage from "localforage";
```

The only problem with that, is that I get tons of errors at compile time from TypeScript. Usages such as these:

```
localForage.getItem("user-settings").then((settings: UserSettings) => {
```

give me errors like these:

```
src\repositories\settings-repository.ts(15,19): error TS2339: Property 'getItem' does not exist on type 'typeo
f "localforage"'.
[08:10:03] gulp-notify: [Error running Gulp] Error: src\repositories\settings-repository.ts(15,19): error TS23
39: Property 'getItem' does not exist on type 'typeof "localforage"'.
src\repositories\settings-repository.ts(19,23): error TS2339: Property 'setItem' does not exist on type 'typeo
f "localforage"'.
```

But then proceed to work at run time. I do have localforage defined in my typings.json:

```
"localforage": "registry:dt/localforage#0.0.0+20160629074517"
```

TypeScript seems to think that this actually exists at localForage.localforage, which throws an undefined exception at run time but does not have compile time errors. I have tried referencing it as such:

```
import { localforage } from "localforage";
```

and (per the docs at https://github.com/localForage/localForage)

```
const localForage:LocalForage = require("localforage");
```

both no longer give compile errors, but do not work at run time.

Comment: hey, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

### Use Generics

You were mostly there with your first shot, but reviewing the typings [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/f56cfc9c61bd7501d8d8ec09e90c486969af85bc/localForage/localForage.d.ts), you can see that the correct syntax is `getItem<T>`. So try this:

```
localForage.getItem<UserSettings>("user-settings")
```

Comment: The first one, import * as localForage from "localforage"; does in fact work in code. The problem is that TypeScript seems to want it as "localforage.localforage.getItem("xxx")..." but it's actually just "localforage.getItem("xxx")..." So the first one works as far as using localforage goes, but it yells at me during compilation.

Comment: Yes, it didn't work. Typescript thinks it should be localForage.localforage.getItem<UserSettings>("user-settings")

Comment: looks like typings are bad, open up a ticket on the localforage github.